# Pseudocode -- how do i 'overwrite' number?

Tags: pseudocode

So, for my group work, we were tasked to write pseudocode. We had just been learning it for, three weeks (almost a month) now.

The question is:
First two numbers are 1 and 2. After that, each succeeding number is the multiple of the two preceding.

1,2,2,4,8,32....

Write pseudocode that will display the set of numbers up to 32.

My groupmates and I basically get the concept of it. So it's like num1 x num2 = num3. Then num3 x num2 = num4, and it loops for 32 times, ect...I was wondering if there is an easier way to 'overwrite' the numbers so that instead of putting 'num4' 'num5' and more, we can just use num 1,2,3 repeatedly since the process is the same.

Set 1 = 1 x 2 = 2

Set 2 = 2 x 2 = 4

Set 3 = 2 x 4 = 8

Set 4 = 8 x 4 = 32

Answer (score 0):

This shall do the trick:

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 2;

while( num2 < 32 )
{
   int temp = num1 * num2;
   print(temp);
   num1 = num2;
   num2 = temp;
}
```